# Include template layout and add components on it

Tags: android, xml, layout, include

I defined a layout and want to use it as template for my other activitys (same background color, distance to margin etc.). So i`m trying to include it by

```
<include layout="@layout/template">
```

That does work. But i want to place buttons on the included layout like this

```
<include layout="@layout/template"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/applyLeave"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/upperEdge"
        style="@style/buttons"/>
    </include>
```

(e.g. @+id/upperEdge is part of the included layout and i want to set the button below the included component)

Is it possible and how do i do this?

Comment: if the parent tag is relative layout add id to your include tag and set the button view below your include tag using layout_below property.If you are using linear layout, set orientation to vertical and add the button view below include tag

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to add Views by XML on include layout.
You can add views, like buttons, after  TAG. Also, if you want to add views dynamically, you can use Java code and add views here.
Here a sample code:

```
//Get your object layout by ID
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_include_layout);

//Create a new button
Button mButton = new Button();
mButton.setText("This is a dynamic button");

//Add button to the layout
myLayout.addView(mButton);
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: ty for your answer. Since it`s not possible to do so, i´m just copying the structure. I appreciate your solution, but i don`t want to create it dynamic in the runtime. regards

Comment: @iamserious ok, but you cannot edit an included layout from external XML  :)